# Мой код выдает ошибку, укажите пожалуйста что исправить

Tags: php

Ошибка на данной строке:

```
User::AddUser($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']);
```

Весь класс с функцией

```
class User {

  public static function AddUser($login, $password) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES (:login, :password)";
    $statment = $db->prepare($sql);

    $statment->bindParam(":login", $login);
    $statment->bindParam(":password", $password);
    $statment->execute();
  }
}
```

C внутренностью самой функции все впорядке , я проверял но сама функция выдает ошибку при вызове , может я коряво вызываю не знаю )))

Заранее спасибо тем кто ответил :)

Comment: Что за ошибка? В 99% надо просто перевести её чтоб понять что не так... Сдаётся мне, у вас ошибка из-за непонятно откуда взявшийся переменной `$db`

Comment: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=firstdatabase;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');

Comment: если вы просто инкрудите файл с этой переменной то добавьте в метод `global $db;`

Comment: @InDevX, [No](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/)